# Looking for a bin­ary-en­coded seri­al­iz­a­tion mechanism

Tags: delphi, serialization, binary, protocols

I was ready to develop an internal communication protocol, and tried to use XML or JSON as a serialization mechanism, but the text mode is less efficient, and lead to a large volume of packets. So, I hope to use a binary serialization encoding mechanism. However, I'm looking for a long time, could not find cross-language, Delphi-supported mechanism.

Comment: For XML there is [Binary XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML) ('Fast Infoset' etc) but I have not seen any Delphi implementations

Comment: Can you elaborate why XML and JSON would lead to more packets than a binary solution?

Comment: There are many cases where any non-compressed binary protocol is going to be less efficient than any text protocol. Exactly why won't compressing and decompressing your text-serialization work for you?  Frankly, cutting yourself off from the world of interoperability versus redesigning your protocol so it's not so noisy, seems like premature optimization.

Comment: Are you sure you really need binary *serialization*? It sounds like you might just need binary *transmission*. You could get that by simply gzipping your transmission stream. Lots of networking libraries support compression "decorators," so any producer or consumer of your data could continue using ordinary text-based encodings, and then let the networking layer take care of the format on the wire.

Comment: As an aside, I felt that the Delphi has been isolated by the world. Protocol-Buf, MessagePack, Avro, BSON, Thrift, etc., these technologies Delphi do not support or does not support perfect.

Comment: If the structure is known, use JSON, with a fixed data order. That is, don't use objects but arrays, replacing the JSON object field names by the JSON array order. This is very efficient, simple, and cross-platform. Binary brings complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) are the most efficient schemes around, unfortunately there very few ports to Delphi at this moment.

- Google Protocol Buffers http://sourceforge.net/projects/protobuf-delphi/

If you are willing to implement for yourself (messagepack is really simple), I suggest you hack *write()* and *parse()* functions of existing libraries like [SuperObject](http://code.google.com/p/superobject/).

You will end up with a very decent library without much effort.

Comment: I need use "it" in Delphi, Java & C#.

Comment: Well, my statement stills valid in that case, no ports to Delphi at this moment :/

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) supports Delphi XE and 2010.

Answer (score 1):

We've implemented an optimized binary format for records and arrays serialization. You can also serialize any object of memory structure easily. It is optimized for speed and used space.

It is part of our mORMot Open Source project, works from Delphi 5 up to XE2. You do not have to use the whole ORM / Client-Server services features of the project, just the `SynCommons.pas` unit.

You can then use our *SynLZ* real-time compression format to make the resulting content even smaller.

See [this blog article](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/12/TDynArray-and-Record-compare/load/save-using-fast-RTTI) and the associated source code.

It has more features than serialization (i.e. sorting, finding, hashing, slicing, reversing...).

It can be used with `TFileBufferWriter/TFileBufferReader` classes to create any custom format, with variable-length encoding of integers, and some other optimizations.

For instance, we use this serialization to store the .map file of all symbols into a .mab binary format: it uses some `TDynArray` instances + *SynLZ*. For a .map text file of 4.44 MB, it creates a .mab of 378 KB. See `TSynMapFile.SaveToStream` and other.

We use this very same format for persistence of in-memory list of objects (see `TSQLRestServerStaticInMemory` class in `SQLite3Commons.pas`). For instance, a 502 KB `People.json` content is stored into a 92 KB `People.data` binary file.

Just a code snippet:

```
function TSQLRestServerStaticInMemory.SaveToBinary(Stream: TStream): integer;
var W: TFileBufferWriter;
    MS: THeapMemoryStream;
    IDs: TIntegerDynArray;
    i, n, f: integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  if (self=nil) or (Stream=nil) then
    exit;
  MS := THeapMemoryStream.Create;
  W := TFileBufferWriter.Create(MS);
  try
    // primitive magic and fields signature for file type identification
    W.Write(RawUTF8(ClassName));
    W.Write(StoredClassProps.SQLTableName);
    n := Length(StoredClassProps.FieldsName);
    W.WriteRawUTF8DynArray(StoredClassProps.FieldsName,n);
    W.Write(pointer(StoredClassProps.FieldType),sizeof(TSQLFieldType)*n);
    // write IDs
    SetLength(IDs,Count);
    with fValue do
      for i := 0 to Count-1 do
        IDs[i] := TSQLRecord(List[i]).fID;
    W.WriteVarUInt32Array(IDs,Count,wkSorted); // efficient ID storage
    // write content, grouped by field (for better compression)
    for f := 0 to High(fStoredClassProps.Fields) do
      with fStoredClassProps.Fields[f]^, fValue do
        for i := 0 to Count-1 do
          GetBinary(TSQLRecord(List[i]),W);
    W.Flush;
    result := StreamSynLZ(MS,Stream,TSQLRESTSERVERSTATICINMEMORY_MAGIC);
  finally
    W.Free;
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The question is about a cross-language solution

Answer (score 0):

BEncode?

Here is the Delphi source:
http://www.torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=bencode&Title=Yes

Wikipedia writes about it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode

There are sourcecodes there for other languages too.